# ¿Se puede actualizar de manera asincrona el dbml que genera LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Estaba haciendo unos cambios en mi base de datos, cuando terminé como siempre los normal es borrar las entidades que sufrieron cambios y volver a arrastras las entidades de la base de datos por medio del explorador de servidores.

Lo que quiero preguntarles es que si hay alguna manera que ese cambio lo haga de manera asíncrona, sin necesidad de tener que volver a dibujar las entidades.

¿Alguien sabe cómo lo puedo lograr?

Answer (score 0):

No creo que sea necesario borrar las entidades que hayan cambiado cada vez que haces un cambio en las tablas de la base de datos.

Para actualizar tu modelo, selecciona el modelo `.dbml` con clic derecho y selecciona la opción "**Run Custom Tool**".

Otra opción es: abrir el modelo con doble clic y en un espacio en blanco presiona clic derecho y selecciona la opción "Validate Model".

Esta captura de pantalla te muestra alguna de las opciones que puedes usar:

> NOTA: La siguiente captura de pantalla pertenece a un modelo con
>   extensión `.edmx`, pero las opciones para actualizar el modelo `dbml`
>   deberían ser similares:

[image: Captura de pantalla de ejemplo]

Answer (score 0):

No hay forma de que los cambios se reflejen en automático.

[`LINQ to SQL`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/) no tiene la capacidad autónoma (de momento, igual y en el futuro esto sea posible) de reflejar los cambios realizados en la base de datos en el contexto del `DataModel`, por lo tanto, así como lo has estado haciendo hasta ahora deberías quitar aquellas entidades y reemplazarlas en el `DataModel` a través del explorador de servidores.

Otra opción es que migres hacia [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx), donde tu proyecto ahora parece tener una reingeniería inversa, tendrías que crear tus clases y el componente se encargaría de crear la estructura de base de datos.

Esto pareciera ser una tarea difícil, no obstante, depende mucho de lo que desees tener en tu proyecto, la proyección que tengas hacia futuro y sobre todo darte cuenta si esto realmente es una solución ya que puede ser demasiado el esfuerzo para automatizar tan solo un poco, de igual forma tomar en cuenta la frecuencia con que cambian tus tablas, bueno, son tantos los puntos a revisar que esto se convertiría en una respuesta inmensa.

En resumen, la respuesta a tu pregunta es **no**, pero si estás abierto a revisar otras opciones sería bueno que plantearas todas tus interrogantes para que puedan ser evaluadas y encontrar la mejor solución.